# Angular js binding strings without quotes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

So i have this project where I want to bind string to `<pre><code>` tags from highlight.js with angular.js but I don't know how to bind it without quotes.
This is the code:

```
<pre><code class="python" ng-bind-html="files[solution]">
                        </code></pre>
```

Comment: *"how to bind it without quotes"*. Not very clear, what do you mean?

Comment: Suppose I have a string "Hello world" I want to bind to <pre><code> tags. Angular binds it like this: <pre><code>"Hello world"</code></pre> and I want it like this : <pre><code>"Hello world"</code></pre>

Comment: @cbass not what I was looking for but thank you anyway

Comment: Maybe you should check `ng-sanitize`. If I remember correctly there is a filter `|html:unsafe` (or maybe `|html:unescape`)

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 could you be a bit more specific on how to use it?

Comment: @Markovlaić Documentation for ng-sanitize and $sanitize can be found here. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

Comment: @Mic thank you this will help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In angular 2 is there a better way to pass a string through an input other than two sets of quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847091/in-angular-2-is-there-a-better-way-to-pass-a-string-through-an-input-other-than)