# In angular 2 is there a better way to pass a string through an input other than two sets of quotes?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to pass a string value instead of an expression through in input. The template will have those string values generated on the server side. I can get this working, but using code similar to the following:

```
<my-app [guidValue]="'some-guid-value'"></my-app>
```

The two sets of quotes (single quotes nested inside double quotes) feels wrong. Is there another way of declaring this as a string value or is this really the way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
<my-app guidValue="some-guid-value"></my-app>
```

This way the value will set as a string in the corresponding input.

Comment: How does this actually work? Is it because `guidValue` is marked as an input parameter that this is possible?

Comment: Yes. It would need to be set as an Input.